# What are the best practices to push API update information to running clients?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Let's say I have a Django REST API and a AngularJS client. Suppose I make a API change so I can implement a new feature to the client.
I push both the API and client changes to production at (almost) the same time. The new API version will be running, but there may still be several clients running old code on users browsers.

What is are the usual practices for pushing and reloading code on the browser?

Comment: You either need to code the API for backwards compatibility. Or you need to ensure that the new clients are rolled out to every customer if the API has changed in such a fashion that it breaks the older clients using it. If your API is dependent on the new client, then it must be rolled out. Otherwise, code defensively for backwards compat. If it's browser based via a web app, then you don't need to "push/reload" code. That's up to them to refresh their browsers/cache.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle these cases is to roll out api changes by versions, much like Facebook and Google do.

Old clients will keep calling the deprecated api while the new ones will call the new api.

Note: when cleaning up older versions you must let your clients know that you are dropping support for the older clients!

Example:

```
//Old deprecated api
GET /api/v1/users
GET /api/v1/cars

//New api - if logic did not change just redirect to old api
GET /api/v2/users (unchanged) --> redirect to /api/v1/users
GET /api/v2/cars new implementation
```

That way you keep your code organized while still supporting old clients.

Comment: Sounds nice with major versions. Should the same approach be used for minor and patch versions?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I think this is only suitable for majors but technically you can version your api however you want, be `v2` or `v2.*`